# React use a form in a modal to pass the inputted data to a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-forms

I am using react-bootstrap/Modal and react-hook-form. I want the user to insert data in the input which after submitting will go to the function where I want to make an object with it.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(update)}>
                        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                <Modal.Title>Edit</Modal.Title>
                            </Modal.Header>
                            <Modal.Body>
                                <label>Description</label>
                                <input name="message" type="text" ref={register} placeholder="description"/>
                            </Modal.Body>
                            <Modal.Footer>
                                <button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                                    Cancel
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" variant="primary" onClick={update}>
                                    Edit
                                </button>
                            </Modal.Footer>
                        </Modal>
                    </form>



//I will need the async function later to await an api call.
const update = (data) => {
        (async () => {
            console.log("data", data)
        })()
    }
```

Thanks for helping!

EDIT:

I found the solution, I had to put the form in the modal but outside the modal components.

```
<Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(update)}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Edit</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
            <label>Description</label>
            <input name="message" type="text" placeholder="description" />
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
            <button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button type="submit" variant="primary" onClick={update}>
                Edit
            </button>
        </Modal.Footer>
    </form>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Hey! Have you tried to use the form inside of the `Modal.Body`? This way you would wrap the ìnput` instead of the whole Modal

Comment: @PedroFilipe I am trying it right now, but what I am trying to achieve is to make the Edit button set off the form onSubmit. If I put my form in the Modal.Body I will get 2 submit buttons (1x Form, 1x Modal.Footer).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `react-hook-forms`, simply can get the result after form submission.

The result object looks like this in your case:
{message: "some message data"}

So, you need to get the "message" property of `data` parameter on `update` function.

**Note:** you pass `message` as the name property of your `input` element so the `data.message` will give you the corresponding data on `input` element which is controlled by `react-hook-forms`

```
const update = (data) => {
        (async () => {
            console.log("data", data.message)
        })()
    }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question (or just my bad English), I have no problem with making the Api call. I am just not sure how to get the data that I input in the form/modal to my function so that I can console.log it there.

Comment: I've updated my answer right now, @JasonMimo